# .focus() doesn't focus when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, focus

.focus() from jQuery 1.9.1 doesn't focus on an iframe every second time. For example, it focuses works the first time, the second time it doesn't, the third time it works, the fourth time it doesn't, etc..

I have created this jsFiddle to test the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/QVuhR/1/ .
Here is the code from jsfiddle:

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var editor = (textEditor.contentDocument) ? textEditor.contentDocument : textEditor.document;
    editor.designMode = "on";

    $("#focusButton").click(function(e){
        $("#textEditor").focus();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="focusButton">Focus Test</button>
<iframe id="textEditor"></iframe>
```

The focusing works fine on Firefox, however it doesn't work on Chrome.

Is there a workaround for this this error for Chrome?

Comment: And by the way, don't reference elements on the page by `id` identifiers; use `document.getElementById("textEditor")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by explicitly blurring first: http://jsfiddle.net/U8JGd/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var editor = (textEditor.contentDocument) ? textEditor.contentDocument : textEditor.document;
    editor.designMode = "on";

    $("#focusButton").click(function(e){
        $("#textEditor").blur();
        $("#textEditor").focus();
    });


});
```

Comment: This did the trick. It also works when you focus on a different element and back on the texteditor as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually redirecting the focus to something else first and then returning the focus back:

```
$("#focusButton").click(function(e){
    $("#focusButton").focus();
    $("#textEditor").focus();
});
```

Not sure if this matches best coding practices, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a workaround:

```
$("#focusButton").click(function(e){
    if (!$("#textEditor").is(":focus"))
        $("#textEditor").focus();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In chrome, focus seems to work as a toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var editor = (textEditor.contentDocument) ? textEditor.contentDocument : textEditor.document;
editor.designMode = "on";

$("#focusButton").click(function(e){
    if(!$("#textEditor").is(":focus"))
    {
    $("#textEditor").focus();
    }
});


});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use this because it doesn't work. Just like the other answer that suggests this. Test your code before you post it: http://jsfiddle.net/7M9Sg/ . And `.focus()` doesn't work as a toggle in Chrome, I'm not sure where you learned that

Comment: Mac or PC? it's working for me on Mac...if it's a bug we should report it. I tested my code before I posted it.

Comment: Mac, Chrome 28.0.1500.95 . And if you tested it, why wouldn't you post a fiddle proving it?

Comment: figured out the bug, reporting it now